# Multiplication over field extension - nonsingular linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory

Multiplication by a fixed element over a field extension is clearly a linear transformation of the bigger field viewed as a vector space over the smaller one. In Stewart's *Intro to Galois*, chapter 6 exercises, there is the question:

When is this transformation nonsingular ?

My linear algebra is rusty to say the least - any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

A field has no zero-divisors, so the kernel of this linear transformation is trivial iff that fixed element is non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

Let $K\subset L$ be a field extension. Let $\alpha\in L$, and let $\sigma_\alpha(k)=\alpha k$ for $k\in L$. Then $\sigma_\alpha$ has an inverse if and only if $\alpha \neq 0$. The inverse is (check) $\sigma_{\alpha^{-1}}$